# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be ma de because the target machine actively refused it>

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

I tried retrieving the data from a web page using the Urllib and i keep getting either `[WinError 10061]` or `[WinError 10060]` i was told by someone(we're both beginners) that the error maybe from my proxy settings but we both don't know exactly how to fix that(we have tried). Here's the code:

```
import urllib.request
g='https://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt'
han=urllib.request.urlopen(g)
for line in han:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

Please what could be the problem, if it is my proxy settings how exactly do i go about fixing that.